# MvvMCross can't close TabActivity when tab exists

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, tabactivity

I have a subclass of `MvxTabActivity` which is the view of a `DeviceOverviewViewModel`. The `DeviceOverviewViewModel` has subviewmodels for the different Tabs. It's working well except one problem. My view has a Close Button which executes the `NavigateBackCommand` of the `DeviceOverviewViewModel`. My view isn't closed when I call the `Close(this)` in my `ViewModel.NavigateBackCommand`.

When I don't setup the TabSpec (see (1) in the Activity code) it is working.

**The output is**:

> mvx:Warning: 45,70 Ignoring close for viewmodel - rootframe's current
>   page is not the view for the requested viewmodel

**Main-Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:...="http://schemas.android.com/apk/..."
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/..."
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/f1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <...widgets.Header
            style="@style/NavBarPhone"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            ...:backButtonResource="@drawable/close_icon" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/DeviceBar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class DeviceOverviewViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public const string ParamInternalDeviceId = "internalDeviceId";

    #region SubViewModels

    private OverviewViewModel _overviewViewModel;

    public OverviewViewModel OverviewViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_overviewViewModel != null)
                return _overviewViewModel;

            _overviewViewModel = new OverviewViewModel(ProductInformation, RegisteredDevice);
            return _overviewViewModel;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public IMvxCommand NavigateBack
    {
        get
        {
            // only for test
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                Close(this);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**:

```
[MvxViewFor(typeof(DeviceOverviewViewModel))]
[Activity(Label = "DeviceOverviewViewModel", Theme = "@style/NoActionBar", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class DeviceOverviewActivity : ...TabActivityBase<DeviceOverviewViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Header = FindViewById<Header>(Resource.Id.header);
        // test with manual call
        Header.BackButton.Click += (s, e) => ViewModel.NavigateBack.Execute();

        // (1) comment this this make it working
        SetupTab(Resource.Id.btnOverview, ViewModel.OverviewViewModel);

        // Bindings
        var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<DeviceOverviewActivity, DeviceOverviewViewModel>();
        // test with binding
        //bindings.Bind(Header.BackButton).For("Click").To(vm => vm.NavigateBack);
        bindings.Apply();
    }

    private void SetupTab(int btnId, IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(btnId.ToString());
        spec.SetIndicator("1");
        spec.SetContent(this.CreateIntentFor(viewModel));
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);

        SetupTabButton(btnId);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you navigating back to?

Comment: Navigate back in my case just means: close the current view and show the view, that called `ShowViewModel<T>()` see the `NavigateBackCommand`

Comment: Is the so called `View` an `Activity`?

Comment: yes ofc :D I just call them views to stay in MVVM terminology.

Comment: So you are calling `Close` inside the VM of the Tab View? Or is it one of the children of the Tab View?

Comment: I call it in the VM `DeviceOverviewViewModel` of the TabView `DeviceOverviewActivity`, because I want to close this one.